# iOS: Collectionview with scroll error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView that is my main menu. It was working perfectly, but now, I have more rows on the menu and user can scroll it.

The cell contains a image, that represents the option icon and a label, that contains the menu title.

After the user scrolls or go to menu and back again, the cells of my collectionview are "messing up". The first row, goes to last row, than, I scroll again and the label is gone...Well, really confusing.

I saw the questions on StackOverflow and tried every solution of it. Like, use [cell setNeedsDisplay] or implementing the method setFrame on my CustomCell.h but the cells still messing up after scroll sometimes.

My code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}
// 2
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 6;
}
// 3
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"MenuOptionCell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = [self.menu dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:90];


    UIView *seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, cell.frame.size.height-5, cell.frame.size.width-20, 1)];
    seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:119.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:seperatorView];



    UIView *seperatorView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];

    NSInteger nsint = idxCollection;
    if(idxCollection == 0)
        seperatorView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-1, 10, 1, cell.frame.size.height)];
    else{
        NSLog(@"%ld", (nsint % 2));
        if((nsint % 2) == 0){
            if(idxCollection != 8)
                seperatorView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-1, 0, 1, cell.frame.size.height)];
            else
                seperatorView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-1, 0, 1, cell.frame.size.height-10)];
        }
    }

    seperatorView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:119.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:seperatorView2];

    switch (idxCollection) {
        case 0:
            lbl.text = @"FIRST MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case 1:
            lbl.text = @"SECOND MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case 2:
            lbl.text = @"THIRD MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"third_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 3:
            lbl.text = @"FOURTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fourth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 4:
            lbl.text = @"FIFTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fifth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 5:
            lbl.text = @"SIXTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sixth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 6:
            lbl.text = @"SEVENTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seventh_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 7:
            lbl.text = @"EIGHTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eigthth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 8:
            lbl.text = @"NINTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ninth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 9:
            lbl.text = @"TENTH MENU";
            [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f]];
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tenth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 10:
            lbl.text = @"ELEVENTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eleventh_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        case 11:
            lbl.text = @"TWELFTH MENU";
            img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twelfth_image.png"];
            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    idxCollection++;
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the problem is you are adding subviews to recycled cells that already have the subviews added

Comment: hi @phix23 but I just add the line separator programmatically, not the cell's label or imagem

Comment: @Lücks You should make a method in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that can take an object and configure the cell based on that object. Something like `-(void)configureCellForObject:(id)object;`. You should move all `UIView` creation calls to an `init*` method (`init` or `initWithCoder:` depending on whether you create them in code or a Storyboard). That way, you'll avoid the problem mentioned by phix23.

Comment: Another problem is the variable idxCollection. You should use indexPath.row instead.

Comment: @phix23 you were correct. idxCollection was a terrible idea. I'm using now: indexPath.row & indexPath.section and it's working perfectly. Thanks!